# nonlinear pyplot imshow colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I spent few hours on this but can't find solution.

I have 2D array of data and I want to plot it as heatmap using `imshow()` function. How can I achieve effect like this? I mean nonlineary distributed colors on colorbar to get better contrast.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521382/nonlinear-colormap-matplotlib), but don't know how to apply it to `imshow().`

[image]

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor

Basically after you get that 2D array of data you scale it to a color array and print in tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the norm parameter:

`plt.imshow(your_data, cmap='afmhot_r', norm=colors.PowerNorm(gamma=0.2))`

Read more:
http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html

Comment: For completeness: In order to use colors.PowerNorm(gamma=0.2) you must import the colors module: from matplotlib import colors